# Swing and bitmaps on retina displays

Tags: java, swing, icons, pixel, retina-display

I've got a Java desktop app that works, amongst other, on OS X.

Now the new MacBook Pro has a retina display and I'm concerned: how is it going to work regarding Swing?

What about when a Java app uses both Swing components and some bitmap graphics (like custom icons / ImageIcon)?

Shall all desktop Java apps be automatically resized (for example by quadrupling every pixel) or am I going to need to create two versions of my icons set (for example one with 24x24 icons and the other with 96x96 icons) and somehow determine that the app is running on a retina display?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that illustrates your area of concern; a new MacBook Pro retina display owner may post a [screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).

Comment: BTW, your 24x24 icon only needs to become a 48x48 icon. Retina doubles the resolution in each dimension, which turns each pixel into four pixels.

Answer (score 7):

Use IconLoader library. It supports HiDPI images http://bulenkov.com/iconloader/ It also provides a way to work with HiDPI images (drawing, etc)

Answer (score 6):

On Apple's Java 6 you can provide multiple versions of the same image. Depending on the screen (retina or not), one or the other image is picked and drawn.

However, those images have to loaded in a special way:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("NSImage://your_image_name_without_extension");
```

For example, if your (regular resolution) image is called: "scissor.png", you have to create a high resolution version "scissor@2x.png" (following the [Apple naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html)) and place both images in the `Resources` directory of your app bundle (yes, you need to [bundle your app](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html)).
Then call:

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("NSImage://scissor");
```

You can use the resulting image in your buttons and it will be drawn with the right resolution magically.

There are two other "tricks" you can use:

1. Using an AffineTransform of (0.5, 0.5) on your Graphics2D object before drawing an Image. Also see [this java-dev message](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Jun/msg00069.html)
2. Creating a high dpi version of your image programmatically using [this hack](http://blog.beatunes.com/2013/04/creating-retina-capable-images-with.html)

The first "trick" (0.5 scaling) by now also works on Oracle's Java 7/8.
I.e. if you draw an image with 0.5 scaling directly to the component's Graphics object, it will be rendered in high resolution on Retina displays (and also with half its original size).

#### Update

Starting with Java 9, there is better built-in support for images with different resolutions via the [MultiResolutionImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/MultiResolutionImage.html) interface. For more details, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51088520/942774).

Comment: Could someone other than the answerer please vote this up or accept it if it actually works, it is not possible to close duplicates against this question until this has been done.

Comment: That's great once I've bundled my app, but I want to see the correct behavior in my IDE before bundling. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I just discovered that I don't need to bundle the app to get the correct behavior. In my IDE, if I have both the old size and the @2x size, it will work when I launch it from my IDE.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that the scaling your images works with on Oracle Java 1.8. I cannot get the `NSImage` hack to work on java 1.7 or 1.8. I think this only works with Java 6 from Mac...

Unless someone else has a better solution, what I do is the following:

Create two sets of icons. 
If you have a `48pixel` width icon create one `48px` @normal `DPI` and another at `96px` with `2x DPI`. Rename the `2xDPI` image as `@2x.png` to conform with apple naming standards.

Subclass `ImageIcon` and call it `RetinaIcon` or whatever.
You can test for a Retina display as follows:

```
public static boolean isRetina() {

boolean isRetina = false;
GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

try {
              Field field = graphicsDevice.getClass().getDeclaredField("scale");
        if (field != null) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object scale = field.get(graphicsDevice);
            if(scale instanceof Integer && ((Integer) scale).intValue() == 2) {
                isRetina = true;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isRetina;
}
```

Make sure to `@Override` the width and height of the new `ImageIcon` class as follows:

```
@Override
public int getIconWidth()
{
    if(isRetina())
    {
        return super.getIconWidth()/2;
    }
    return super.getIconWidth();
}

@Override
public int getIconHeight()
{
    if(isRetina())
    {
        return super.getIconHeight()/2;
    }
    return super.getIconHeight();
}
```

Once you have a test for the retina screen and your custom width/height methods overridden you can customise the `painIcon` method as follows:

```
@Override
public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) 
{
    ImageObserver observer = getImageObserver();

    if (observer == null) 
    {
        observer = c;
    }

    Image image = getImage();
    int width = image.getWidth(observer);
    int height = image.getHeight(observer);
    final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create(x, y, width, height);

    if(isRetina())
    {
        g2d.scale(0.5, 0.5);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, observer);
    g2d.scale(1, 1);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

I do not know how this will work with multiple screens though- is there anyone else that can help out with that???

Hope this code helps out anyway!

Jason Barraclough.

Here is an example of using the scaling as mentioned above:
[RetinaIcon is on the left. ImageIcon is on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w2mD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, that works also when the icons are used in the apple menu. There the icon is automatically greyed. So I have implemented a class DenseIcon which paints densely:

```
public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    if(getImageObserver() == null) {
        g.drawImage(getImage0(), x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight(), c);
    } else {
        g.drawImage(getImage0(), x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight(), getImageObserver());
    }
}
```

How to hook into the greying I have not yet figured out. So as a kludge we return a low res image so that the menu can do its modifications:

```
public Image getImage() {
    Image image = getImage0().getScaledInstance(
            getIconWidth(),
            getIconHeight(),
            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image, getDescription());
    return icon.getImage();
}
```

You find the code of the full class here on [gist](https://gist.github.com/jburse/bf66f9e84104ad7cfdd5c04fdbaa68c9#file-denseicon-java). You need to instantiate the icon class with an URL to an image that is twice the size. Works for 2K displays.

Answer (score 0):

This how icons look like on my retina macbook '12:

[image]

On the left side icons in IntelliJ IDEA 11 (swing app) and on the right side IDEA 12 which is claimed to be *retinized*. As you can see automatically resized icons (on the left) looks pretty ugly.

As far as I know, they, [just like the guys from Chrome team](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111101&q=remove%20pdf&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary), made it by providing double sized icons.