# Java swing + UI scale

Tags: java, swing, scale

I need to create an application with interface scaling. I have a button with icon inside and jpanel, that hold this button. The problem is that when scale is on - an icon is blurred and to fix this, I use downscaling in paintComponent. When system scale is on, I have normal image, as a result. But JPanel still have a scaled size. I tryed to override JPanel paintComponent too, but as a result I had too small buttons, because downscale on button and donwscale on JPanel work togeather. I can't use scale only from JPanel, when I click a button, it take a scaled size and image blurred again. 
This is a simple example.

[image]

And the code is:

```
public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1.5");
    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\1.png"));
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
    j.setVisible(true);
    j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    j.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    img = img.getScaledInstance((int) (60 * 1.5),(int) (60 * 1.5),Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

    JToggleButton tb = new JToggleButton(){
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.scale(0.67,0.67);
            super.paintComponent(g2);
        }
    };
    tb.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

    JToggleButton tb2 = new JToggleButton(){
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.scale(0.67,0.67);
            super.paintComponent(g2);
        }
    };
    tb2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));


    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(){

    };
    jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    jPanel.add(tb);
    jPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);



    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    content.add(jPanel);

    j.setContentPane(content);
    j.pack();
}
```

}
I use java10. 
Thank you.

Comment: Scaling is complicated, as it affects more things then just the rendering of the graphics, it effects the coordinate system as well.  I think, as a generally better solution, you will want to scale the icons independently based on the system scale

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Java 9 hdpi display support - multi-resolution images - name convention and loading in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802885/java-9-hdpi-display-support-multi-resolution-images-name-convention-and-load)

Comment: If I will independently scale image, it been scale again from system scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You render your UI with scaling factor of 1.5: all UI including icons and images is scaled so that it displays correctly on a High DPI display. If image does not scale, it would be too small for a higher DPI setting.

If your application supports High DPI displays, i.e. *UI scaling*, you should provide images of different resolutions. See [MultiResolutionImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/MultiResolutionImage.html) in Java 9.

You can find sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51088520/572834) to a related question.

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71101882/572834) to another question includes the sample which demonstrates the usage of `MultiResolutionImage`.